# Get result of Func<Task<IResponse>> inside timeout check

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm kinda new at async programming so don't uderstand many things. Please, I need a little bit more help. I did as was recommened in my other question.

```
public async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAsync<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> sendAsync)
{
        int timeout = 15;
        if (await Task.WhenAny(sendAsync, Task.Delay(timeout) == sendAsync))
        {
            return await sendAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("time out!!!");
        }
}
```

But I need to get a result of `sendAsync()` and return it. So have I questions:

1) What the best way to do that and how to use `Task.Delay` with `Func<Task<TResponse>>`(or may be something instead of it)? I can't figure out how convert(or something) Func to Task.

2) It seems that return `await sendAsync()` inside if permorms request once more. It is not great. Can I get result of my `Func<Task<..>>` inside if somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new in async programming - it's better to not put too much stuff in one statement and better split that:

```
public async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAsync<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> sendAsync) {
    int timeout = 15;
    // here you create Task which represents ongoing request
    var sendTask = sendAsync();
    // Task which will complete after specified amount of time, in milliseconds
    // which means your timeout should be 15000 (for 15 seconds), not 15
    var delay = Task.Delay(timeout);
    // wait for any of those tasks to complete, returns task that completed first
    var taskThatCompletedFirst = await Task.WhenAny(sendTask, delay);
    if (taskThatCompletedFirst == sendTask) {
        // if that's our task and not "delay" task - we are fine
        // await it so that all exceptions if any are thrown here
        // this will _not_ cause it to execute once again
        return await sendTask;
    }
    else {
        // "delay" task completed first, which means 15 seconds has passed
        // but our request has not been completed
        throw new Exception("time out!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please also explain why "await sendTask" inside "if" won't execute second time? it is seems kinda magic place.

Comment: await doesn't execute anything. In very simplified terms in means something like "while this task executes - do something else, when task completes - return back here and continue executing the rest of the method)". This task is already completed, so await will just check if it there were any exceptions and throw them.

Comment: @Amelina but I'd better just read some article about async\await instead of relying on simplified descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Request is sent twice because sendAsync is a Func returning Task, different on each call. You call it first under `Task.WhenAny()` and repeat in operator `return await sendAsync()`.

To avoid this duplicated call you should save a task to variable and pass that task to both calls:

```
public async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAsync<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> sendAsync)
{
    int timeout = 15;
    var task = sendAsync();
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout) == task))
    {
        return await task;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("time out!!!");
    }
}
```

`await` on completed task will just return its result without rerunning the task.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain what the difference?